# Double comparatives: "more preferable"

Tags: vocabulary, comparatives, style-manuals

[Fowler reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=w1WuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA646&dq=%22sometimes%20the%20double%20comparative%20form%20more%20preferable%20is%20used%22&hl=es&pg=PA646#v=onepage&q=%22sometimes%20the%20double%20comparative%20form%20more%20preferable%20is%20used%22&f=false)

> Sometimes the double comparative form  ***more preferable***  is used.
> The word *more* is of course unnecessary, since *preferable* by itself
> means ‘more desirable (than)’. Like other comparatives, it is
> therefore intensified by *far, much, infinitely*, etc.

[Garner adds that](https://books.google.es/books?id=mSjnCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA720&dq=%22inherently%20a%20comparative%20adjective%2C%20shouldn%E2%80%99t%20be%20preceded%20by%20more%22&hl=es&pg=PA720#v=onepage&q=%22inherently%20a%20comparative%20adjective,%20shouldn%E2%80%99t%20be%20preceded%20by%20more%22&f=false) it's "inherently a comparative adjective taking *to*, not *than*".

[For the ahdictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=certain) "It is often claimed that **certain** is an absolute term like **unanimous** or **paramount** and cannot be modified, yet phrases such as *fairly/quite **certain*** are readily understood as expressing varying degrees of confidence, especially when they refer to a person. Since **certain** must always suggest overall confidence, its range is restricted to the upper range; one is less likely to be *slightly*, *somewhat*, or *a little bit **certain***."

What other adjectives/adverbs follow this pattern?

Comment: What pattern are you referring to?

Comment: @tchrist _much/far/*more preferable_

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _"They all do"_. do what exactly???

Comment: They almost all follow the **usual** rules. Garner is saying that 'more preferable' is sometimes encountered, 'preferable' being a 'covert' comparative adjective, whereas 'more better/bigger/happier/worse/...' thankfully aren't found in use to any significant degree. Garner is using the term 'comparative adjective' in a peculiar and unhelpful way – 'an adjective showing comparison' rather than 'positive / _comparative_ / superlative form of a typical adjective'; 'better', 'bigger' etc all take 'than', of course. Look for Garner's stipulative definition here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We would more rather you made a more superior answer than comment.

Comment: @tchrist "In a phrase like ''inferior wine'' the meaning is ‘inadequate’ rather than ‘less good’".  In the language of marketing, and sometimes in general social contexts, _superior_ is used as a kind of blind or absolute comparative (= above the average in quality) ( _a superior bungalow; made of superior leather ; a very superior box of chocolates_ )

Comment: @GJC Good parallel. And 'more inferior' etc are similarly unidiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As too for the same reason are *more optimal/pessimal, more maximal/minimal, more superior/supreme* all similarly unidiomatic. But **other** Latin-derived comparative or superlative adjectives have come to allow for degree modifiers in English, like *more senior/junior/extreme*.  (You don't hear anybody saying *more teterrimous* but probably because they wouldn't say *teterrimous* either.) These objections differ from those raised against *more never, more everywhere, more one of a kind, more final, more dead, more annihilated, more ubiquitous, more unique, more ultimate*.

Comment: @tchrist Even if you can't find analysis of this, or supporting references, it's valuable and sound enough to be put in an 'answer'. I can't remember these 'comparator adjectives' being addressed in any other thread. If you're unhappy about giving an unsupported answer, perhaps some kind mod would Wiki it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _Wiki it_?

Comment: How about *very unique*? This is frequently cited as meaningless, because "unique" is considered absolute.

Comment: @Barmar _Unless the thing is the only one of its kind, **rarity** 
does not make it **unique**, so if a thing is one
in a million, logically there would be two things in two
million. Arguably, our modern culture lacks and does not want
absolutes, in intellectual life or in language: The word is also used to
mean ‘particularly remarkable, special, or unusual’. As such it is
gradable, as some of the following examples demonstrate, and
behaves grammatically like its synonyms remarkable, special,
etc. All modern monolingual dictionaries recognize this meaning,
usually with a warning__

Comment: Looking at grading comparatives like better, taller, worse, more beautiful, it can be done, but not by adding a 'more'. _This is better, but that is better still/yet._  / _This is even worse._ / She is even / yet / still more beautiful_. / _B is preferable to A, but C is even more to be preferred._ (Usually, ... 'better still.')

Comment: @ConsciousClay Would you demand 'The return match was more nearly even' instead of 'The return match was more even'? The ratios of hits in a raw Google search for "was/were more even" to "was/were more nearly even" are in each case over 1000 : 1, and though false positives admittedly reduce the true ratios a lot, preferred usage is clear. [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/07/full-fuller-fullest.html) notes that Webster's Second Edition lists 'fuller' and 'fullest' as inflected forms of 'full', and gives a balanced view on their acceptability.

Comment: @ConsciousClay X is a good wine, but there are some that are preferable. Of these, Y is more preferable than Z.